# Concealed cistern basket won't come out

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

My Geberit concealed toilet cistern is leaking into the bowl.
I have removed the flush valve and changed the washer but it is still leaking. I have tried to remove the basket to change the washer but it won't come out. It is an old model(109.200.00.1) from 2009. Is there a way to get this basket out?

Comment: Pics or links to the instructions might help us help you.